# Should I try to enforce strong data-typing in my JavaScript classes?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, standards, typing

I'm writing a JavaScript library that I intend to use a lot, and may eventually release publicly. Right now, I'm doing a lot of function and "class constructor" definitions like this:

```
function Point(x, y)
{
  this.y = typeof y !== 'undefined' ? y : 0;
  this.x = typeof x !== 'undefined' ? x : 0;

  if (typeof this.x === "number" && typeof this.y === "number")
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  else if (this.x instanceof Point && typeof this.y === "undefined")
  {
    this.x = x.x;
    this.y = x.y;
  }
  else
  {
    throw ("Point() Constructor: Invalid arguments.");
  }
}
```

This allows me not only to have "two different constructors" for this "class", but it also ensures that when the object is instantiated, it has the expected types in it, and a semi useful error is thrown if not.

This all seemed like a good idea for a while, but now that I'm getting into it a ways, and I've gotten a look at other production JavaScript source (like Mozilla's stuff for example), I'm starting to have second thoughts because people don't really do this. And now I'm wondering, "why am I trying to force a loosely-typed language to conform to these strict typing standards?"

What is the expected standard for JavaScript libraries to follow when it comes to error handling and type checking?

May be slightly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176561/how-do-i-work-with-an-existing-javascript-codebase-because-of-dynamic-typing), but I'm  looking to write my own stuff.

Comment: i don't think you're enforcing typing, you're allowing flexible input, just like `Date()`...

Comment: @dandavis maybe it wasn't the best example. I'm more concerned with all the type checking. Even on a simple function with ONE parameter, I'm doing a type check, and then throwing an error if the wrong type was given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By trying to enforce strong typing, you are ultimately working against the language.  This approach has its places, but it can much easier accomplished by using something like [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

The biggest question you have to ask yourself with this approach, is if you have thought out and covered all of the problem domains you need to handle in your application, and can this extend to solve other problems that you might not thought of.  If it is, will this approach be too difficult to maintain, e.g. do you feel that you can take the time and care to create all of your constructors,functions, etc. in this manner to make sure that everything follows the standards set in place?  This is important, because although JavaScript handles what you are doing, you could say this is not in the "spirit" of the language, which more or less means that the language will not help you achieve your goal in writing code this way.

Comment: If you want to go down this road (i.e. beyond just the occasional type-check), I suggest using some sort of tool to help with it. TypeScript would be one option (as Kevin mentioned). Another would be [flow](http://flowtype.org/) (my preference since it works with native JS). For runtime type checking, also check out https://github.com/codemix/babel-plugin-typecheck.